# references of modular representations for finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

What is modular representation for finite groups? I tried to find a book to understanding that but I could not find a good one. Are there any useful references?

Comment: There are several ones mentioned in a related MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55983

Comment: Serre's book covers the basics pretty well.

Comment: It would help to get a bit more information about your background (Do you know ordinary representation theory? On the level of characters or of algebras and modules?) and what you are aiming for (Description of the basic setup? Working with modular character tables and decomposition numbers? Brauers theorems? .....)